# Close drawer automatically return MaterialApp and Scaffold black screen after Navigator.pop(context);

Tags: google-maps, flutter, dart

Hy Guys I'm trying try to close drawer inside material app but it is not working. My code:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return MaterialApp(
    home: currentLocation == null ? Container(
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      child: Center(
        child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
      ),
    ):

    Scaffold(
        drawer: Drawer(
            child: ListView(
               children: <Widget>[
                ListTile(
                  leading: CircleAvatar(),
                  title: Text("test app"),
                  subtitle: Text("nn"),
                ),
                ListTile(leading: Icon(Icons.multiline_chart), title: Text("check gps.."),
                    onTap: () { 
                   _checkgps();
                     Navigator.pop(context);
                    }
                    ),
           appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('test app'),

        ),
        body:  GoogleMap(

          initialCameraPosition:
          CameraPosition(target: LatLng(currentLocation.latitude,
              currentLocation.longitude), zoom: 17),
          onMapCreated: _onMapCreated,
          mapType: _currentMapType,
          compassEnabled: true,
          myLocationEnabled: true,
          polylines: Set<Polyline>.of(_mapPolylines.values),
          markers: Set<Marker>.of(markers.values),
         )

       );

      }
```

But when i press list item 1 ( checkgps )  `Navigator.pop(context);` going to black screen and not see google maps. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you are calling this widget directly from you run app and because of that it is causing error.

Your appbar was also at wrong place.

checkout below code.

```
void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}


class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return  MaterialApp(
        title: 'Flutter Demo',
        home: Scaffold(body: DeleteWidget()),
    );
  }
}

class DeleteWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const DeleteWidget({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _DeleteWidgetState createState() => _DeleteWidgetState();
}

class _DeleteWidgetState extends State<DeleteWidget> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return currentLocation == null
        ? Container(
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            child: Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            ),
          )
        : Scaffold(
            drawer: Drawer(
              child: ListView(children: <Widget>[
                ListTile(
                  leading: CircleAvatar(),
                  title: Text("test app"),
                  subtitle: Text("nn"),
                ),
                ListTile(
                    leading: Icon(Icons.multiline_chart),
                    title: Text("check gps.."),
                    onTap: () {
                      _checkgps();
                      Navigator.pop(context);
                    }),
              ]),
            ),
            appBar: AppBar(
              title: Text('test app'),
            ),
            body: GoogleMap(
              initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
                  target: LatLng(
                      currentLocation.latitude, currentLocation.longitude),
                  zoom: 17),
              onMapCreated: _onMapCreated,
              mapType: _currentMapType,
              compassEnabled: true,
              myLocationEnabled: true,
              polylines: Set<Polyline>.of(_mapPolylines.values),
              markers: Set<Marker>.of(markers.values),
            ),
          );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are not popping the `Drawer`'s context, you are popping the `MaterialApp`'s context.

Also it is a good idea to split your app into small piece of widgets, so your drawer content must be placed in another widget. I've made these changes, try out this code:

```
void main() {
    runApp(MyApp());
}


class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return  MaterialApp(
            title: 'Flutter Demo',
            home: Scaffold(body: DeleteWidget()),
        );
    }
}

class DeleteWidget extends StatefulWidget {
    const DeleteWidget({Key key}) : super(key: key);

    @override
    _DeleteWidgetState createState() => _DeleteWidgetState();
}

class _DeleteWidgetState extends State<DeleteWidget> {
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return currentLocation == null
                ? Container(
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            child: Center(
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            ),
        )
                : Scaffold(
            drawer: _DrawerContent(),
            appBar: AppBar(
                title: Text('test app'),
            ),
            body: GoogleMap(
                initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
                        target: LatLng(
                                currentLocation.latitude, currentLocation.longitude),
                        zoom: 17),
                onMapCreated: _onMapCreated,
                mapType: _currentMapType,
                compassEnabled: true,
                myLocationEnabled: true,
                polylines: Set<Polyline>.of(_mapPolylines.values),
                markers: Set<Marker>.of(markers.values),
            ),
        );
    }
}

class _DrawerContent extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Drawer(
            child: ListView(children: <Widget>[
                ListTile(
                    leading: CircleAvatar(),
                    title: Text("test app"),
                    subtitle: Text("nn"),
                ),
                ListTile(
                        leading: Icon(Icons.multiline_chart),
                        title: Text("check gps.."),
                        onTap: () {
                            _checkgps();
                            Navigator.pop(context);
                        }),
            ]),
        );
  }
}
```

With the `Drawer` content in another widget when you call `Navigator.pop(context);` it will pop the drawer context not the Page context where the `Drawer` is.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of calling `navigator.pop` you can use

```dart
Navigator.of(context).maybePop();
```